# trigger form validation from button in another form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces with JSF-2 on Glassfish, trying to cross validate a form.
Here's the scenario:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:messages id="msgs" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
    some input fields with validation
</h:form>

<h:form id="form_upload">
    some upload fields that dont trigger validations
</h:form>

<h:form id="buts">
    <p:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="#{bean.save}"
        update=":form1 :form1:msgs" process=":form1">
</h:form>
```

I would like button save to trigger validations on form1, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute `process` and specify each components you want to be processed on the server:

```
<p:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="#{bean.save}"
     process=":form1 :form_upload" update=":form1" />
```

Don't forget to put a `p:messages` somewhere in `:form1`, else you want to update it too.

Read more about [AJAX on JSF here](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxPOSTForm).

Comment: thanks @eljunior, for some reason I can't get it to work, it just ignores the button. Maybe I'm failing at updating messages but the colour of the input fields should change and it ain't working either. I updated the question, see anything wrong? thanks

Comment: Bruno, the only thing I noticed was that the p:commandButton isn't closed. Is it the same way in your actual code? Otherwise, I tested here with the same code (plus a few input fields) and it worked alright.

Comment: btw, if you are using the Mojarra implementation for JSF, sometimes it helps to catch errors to set the context-param PROJECT_STAGE. Try placing this in you *web.xml*: `<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>`

Comment: thats just a copy/paste mistake @eljunior. I just coded a new xhtml for the test purpose and it don't work. This is very weird since I'm typing exactly what you said. Take a look here: http://cl.ly/code/0Z3N3X1H0K3o , 3 forms as mentioned, you can use the button on the 1st one and it works, the last button doesnt trigger the validations....

Comment: I'm using Development, it doesnt show any errors, not even on glassfish console :(

Comment: oh, I see now! You should use JSF's `h:head` instead of plain HTML head element! That's because PrimeFaces need to include some Javascript in the head element of the page, and you need to use h:head for that to work.

Comment: I do have h:head on my main project, and if I add it to the test xhtml, still doesnt work for some reason... sorry for all the trouble...

Comment: also, button2 resets all form1 fields.

Comment: That's weird, man... What do you have in the bean code? Maybe you could try to create a brand-new bean too, together with the new xhtml, and try to isolate the problem with the minimum of components on the page.

Comment: I'm about to quit. I'll just put the buttons on the same form, it will be ugly but since it's purely academic it will have to do. I don't need any calls on the bean to test the validations so I'm assuming it's not a bean problem... thanks @eljunior for everything!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I don't have any other idea to test out. Just in case, I was testing with Mojarra 2.0.9 and PrimeFaces 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrimeFaces' `<p:remoteCommand>`

```
<h:form id="form1">        
    some input fields with validation
    <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="@form" action="#{bean.save}" />
</h:form>
```

sample remote call:

```
<h:form id="buts">
   <p:commandButton value="Save" type="button" onclick="rc()" />
</h>
```